# Array declaration inside struct using predefined constant in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, constants

I want to declare an array inside a *structure* with a **predefined constant size**, but it gives me this error : *expected a ']'*.

```
#define MAX_SZAMJEGY 200;

struct szam {

    int szj[MAX_SZAMJEGY];
    bool negative;
};
```

Comment: remove ; from define

Comment: Or even better, replace the define with `constexpr std::size_t MAX_SZAMJEGY = 200;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Macro expands to

```
int szj[200;];
```

which is not valid C++ code.

remove ; from `#define MAX_SZAMJEGY 200;`

Answer (score 4):

A preferred C++ solution is to use constants rather than macros. This way you will not have a semicolon problem, and it comes with tons of other benefits as well. Here is how:

(C++ 98):

```
static const size_t MAX_SZAMJEGY 200;

struct szam {

    int szj[MAX_SZAMJEGY];
    bool negative;
};
```

(C++11)

```
static constexpr size_t MAX_SZAMJEGY=200;

struct szam {

    int szj[MAX_SZAMJEGY];
    bool negative;
};
```

And while you are on it, and if you are using C++11, you might as well replace C-style array with C++ `std::array`. While it doesn't make too much of a difference, it is slightly more convenient to use.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
#define MAX_SZAMJEGY 200
```

instead of

```
#define MAX_SZAMJEGY 200;
```

(the semicolon enters the macro)